# After zooming in chart js x axis labels does not change as per current zoom

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I have build one chart using chart js library. When I am trying to zoom the chart it is working fine.
But the x axis labels does not change. Means suppose there are x axis labels from 10-100 and I m zooming between 40-60. Then after zoom my x axis labels should be 40,45,50,60.
Currently it is showing only 40 and 60.

I have tried onzoomcomplete method. There I have tried to set ticks labels using custom data.
But it is somehow not working.